# Unable to get message from channel in laravel echo

Tags: javascript, laravel, websocket, laravel-5.3, laravel-echo

Here is `socket.js` code

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();

redis.subscribe("broadcast-channel", function(err, count) {
});

redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    const event = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + event.event, event.data);
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
});
```

Here is client code

```
 var Echo = new Echo({
             broadcaster: 'socket.io',
             host: window.location.hostname + ':3000'
         });
         Echo.channel("broadcast-channel")
             .listen("FieldWasUpdated", function(e) {
                 console.log(e);
             });
```

In chrome development tools I see that events come through websockets but console.log is never called. I tried different formats for `io.emit` (`event.event, channel, event.data`, `channel, event`, `etc...`) call but no one of them worked.

Comment: Does the event name definitely have the `.` in front of it?